# Catching intruder

Tags: 14.04, scripts, lock-screen, hacking

I work in a company where is better to not forget locking your pc before leaving it, because the first person who finds it's unlocked will use all his strength to embarrass me on social networks and files and do something funny and embarrassing.

I'm trying to find out how to leave my pc unlocked and catch (for embarrassing purposes) everyone who tries to embarrass me.

So, as a new ubuntu user I would be happy if you could propose some ideas.

I do understand that this question is kinda trivial, but I think possible answers can hold quite a value for the community.

Answer (score 2):

CCTV will help you. 
Or forensics.
But that's outside the scope of this forum, I'd say.

If you're leaving your session unlocked (which is a very bad idea alone - especially that it seems you're not really in a safe environment) - whoever does anything on your computer with you logged, will do it as your user. It's your responsibility to protect your own account - I'd say.

Not trying to be rude here - just realistic.